# Error 1 error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'exercises.h': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, vector, include

So i got 2 files one is a .cpp and the other one is a header.

this one is the .cpp file

```
#include "exercises.h"

using namespace std;

/* Tema 1 */

/* Exercitiul 1
   Scrieti o functie care sa calculeze suma cifrelor unui numar natural.
*/

unsigned int computeDigitSum(unsigned int number)
{
    int sum = 0;
    while (number)
    {
        sum = sum + number % 10;
        number = number / 10;
    }
    return sum;
}

/* Exercitiul 2
   Scrieti o functie care verifica daca un an este bisect.
*/

bool isLeap(unsigned int year)
{
    if (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) return true;
    else if (year % 400 == 0) return true;
    return false;
}

/* Exercitiul 3
   Scrieti o functie care sa testeze daca un numar este palindrom.
   Un numar este palindrom daca citit de la dreapta la stanga este egal cu numarul citit de la stanga la dreapta.
   Exemple: 36463 este palindrom, dar 2646 nu este palindrom.
*/

bool isPalindrome(int number)
{
    int aux = number, invertedNumber = 0;
    while (number > 0)
    {
        invertedNumber = invertedNumber * 10 + number % 10;
        number = number / 10;
    }
    if (aux == invertedNumber) return true;
    return false;
}

/* Exercitiul 4
   Scrieti un program, care, pentru o luna si un an date, calculeaza numarul de zile din luna respectiva
   (folositi o functie separata care verifica daca un an este bisect).
   Exemplu: pentru luna februarie din anul 2004, numarul de zile este 29.
*/

unsigned int computeNumberOfDays(unsigned int year, unsigned int month)
{
    if (month == 0 || month > 12)
        return 0;
    if (month == 2)
    {
        if (isLeap(year)) return 29;
        else return 28;
    }
    else if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) return 30;
    else return 31;
}

/* Exercitiul 5
   Scrieti o functie care calculeaza cifra de control a unui numar natural.
   Cifra de control se obtine calculand suma cifrelor numarului,
   apoi suma cifrelor numarului obtinut etc., pana se ajunge la o singura cifra.
   Exemplu: 4879 -> 28 -> 10 -> 1.
*/

unsigned int computeControlDigit(unsigned int number)
{
    while (number > 9)
    {
        number = computeDigitSum(number);
    }
    return number;
}

/* Exercitiul 6
   Spunem ca un numar natural este perfect daca este egal cu suma divizorilor sai strict mai mici decat el.
   Scrieti o functie care verifica daca un numar este perfect.
   Exemplu: 28 este un numar perfect deoarece 28 = 1 + 2 + 4 + 7 + 14.
   Sa se determine toate numerele perfecte mai mici ca un numar natural n dat.
   Exemplu: pentru n = 1000, se vor determina numerele 6, 28, 496.
*/

bool isPerfect(unsigned int number)
{
    int sum = 0, i;
    if (number == 0) return false;
    for (i = 1; i <= number/2; i++)
    {
        if (number % i == 0)
            sum = sum + i;
    }
    if (sum == number) return true;
    return false;
}
vector getPerfects(unsigned int upperLimit)
{
    vector v;
    v.length = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < upperLimit; i++)
    {
        if (isPerfect(i))
        {
            v.values[v.length] = i;
            v.length++;
        }
    }
    return v;
}

/* Exercitiul 7
   Sa se testeze daca un numar este prim.
   Exemple: 1000003 este prim, dar 1000002 este compus deoarece este divizibil prin 3.
*/

bool isPrime(int number)
{
    int i;
    if (number < 0)
        number = abs(number);
    for (i = 2; i <= number/2; i++)
        if (number % i == 0)
        return false;
    if (number < 2)
        return false;
    return true;
}

/* Exercitiul 8
   Doua numere naturale impare consecutive si prime se numesc numere prime gemene.
   Folosind testul de primalitate implementat anterior, determinati primele n perechi de numere prime gemene.
   Exemplu: Primele n = 3 perechi de numere prime gemene sunt (3, 5), (5, 7) si (11, 13).
*/

bool areTwinPrimes(unsigned int number1, unsigned int number2)
{
    if (isPrime(number1) && isPrime(number2) && number2 - number1 == 2)
        return true;
    return false;
}
matrix getTwinPrimes(unsigned int count)
{
    matrix m;
    m.columns = 2;
    m.lines = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 3; i < count - 2; i++)
        if (areTwinPrimes(i, i + 2))
    {
        m.values[m.lines][0] = i;
        m.values[m.lines][1] = i + 2;
        m.lines++;
    }
    return m;
}

/* Exercitiul 9
   Se citeste un tablou de numere intregi.
   Scrieti o functie care determina diferenta maxima (in modul) dintre oricare doua elemente ale vectorului.
   Exemplu: pentru tabloul (1, 3, 2, 7, 11, 3, 2), diferenta maxima (in modul) este 12.
*/

unsigned int getMaxDifference(vector v)
{
    int i, j, maxDifference = 0, difference;
    for (i = 0; i < v.length - 1; i++)
        for (j = i + 1; j < v.length; j++)
    {
        difference = v.values[i] - v.values[j];
        difference = abs(difference);
        if (difference > maxDifference)
            maxDifference = difference;
    }
    return maxDifference;
}

/* Exercitiul 10
   Se citeste un tablou de numere intregi.
   Sa se determine, printr-o singura parcurgere a sa, pozitia de inceput si lungimea celei mai lungi secvente de elemente egale.
   Daca exista mai multe secvente de lungimi egale, se va determina secventa cu pozitia de inceput minima.
   Exemplu: pentru tabloul (1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 5, 5, 5), se vor determina pozitia 2 si lungimea 3.
*/

sequence getMaxSequence(vector v)
{
    sequence maxSumSequence;
    maxSumSequence.startPosition = 1;
    maxSumSequence.length = 1;

    int i, j, maxSum = v[0], sum = v[0];
    for (i = 0; i < v.length - 1; i++)
    {
        sum = v.values[i];
        for (j = i + 1; j < v.length; j++)
        {
            sum = sum + v.values[j];
            if (sum > maxSum)
            {
                maxSum = sum;
                maxSumSequence.startPosition = i;
                maxSumSequence.length = j - i + 1;

            }
        }
    }

    return maxSumSequence;
}

/* Exercitiul 11
   Se da un vector de numere intregi.
   Sa se determine subsecventa pentru care suma elementelor componente este maxima.
   Daca exista mai multe subsecvente cu aceasta proprietate, se va determina ultima subsecventa gasita.
   Exemplu: pentru tabloul (2, 3, 4, 2, 9, 2, 1, 7, 3), subsecventa este (9, 2, 1, 7).
*/

sequence getMaxSumSequence(vector v)
{
    sequence maxSumSequence;
    maxSumSequence.startPosition = 0;
    maxSumSequence.length = 1;

    int i, j, maxSum = 0, sum;
    for (i = 0; i < v.length - 1; i++)
    {
        sum = v.values[i];
        for (j = i + 1; j < v.length; j++)
        {
            sum = sum + v.values[j];
            if (sum > maxSum)
            {
                maxSum = sum;
                maxSumSequence.startPosition = i;
                maxSumSequence.length = j - i + 1;

            }
        }
    }

    return maxSumSequence;
}

/* Exercitiul 12
   Se citeste un tablou de numere intregi.
   Sa se rearanjeze elementele astfel incat cele pare sa apara inaintea celor impare.
   In cadrul subsecventei de numere pare, respectiv impare, elementele trebuie sa apara in ordinea in care erau in tabloul initial.
   Exemplu: tabloul (2, 3, 4, 2, 9, 2, 1, 7, 3) va fi rearanjat in (2, 4, 2, 2, 3, 9, 1, 7, 3).
*/

vector orderElements(vector v)
{

    int vectorAuxiliar[100], i, position = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < v.length; i++)
        vectorAuxiliar[i] = v.values[i];
    for (i = 0; i < v.length; i++)
        if (vectorAuxiliar[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
        v.values[position] = vectorAuxiliar[i];
        position++;
        }
    for (i = 0; i < v.length; i++)
        if (vectorAuxiliar[i] % 2 != 0)
        {
        v.values[position] = vectorAuxiliar[i];
        position++;
        }
    return v;
}

/* Exercitiul 13
   Se considera un tablou cu n elemente.
   Sa se decida daca exista un element majoritar (cu numarul de aparitii mai mare decat n/2).
*/

bool containsMajorElement(vector v)
{
    int i, j, elementCount;
    for (i = 0; i < v.length; i++)
    {
        elementCount = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < v.length; j++)
            if (v.values[i] == v.values[j])
                elementCount++;
        if (elementCount > v.length / 2) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/* Exercitiul 14
   Se considera o matrice patratica cu n elemente.
   Sa se interschimbe liniile si coloanele acesteia astfel incat, in matricea finala, elementele de pe diagonala principala sa fie in ordine descrescatoare.
   Sa se afiseze matricea initiala si matricea dupa fiecare operatie.
*/

matrix sortDiagonalElements(matrix m)
{
    int i, j, x, z, aux;
    for (i = 0; i < m.lines - 1; i++)
        for (j = i + 1; j < m.lines; j++)
            if (m.values[i][i] < m.values[j][j])
            {
                for (x = 0; x < m.lines; x++)
                {
                   aux = m.values[x][j];
                   m.values[x][j] = m.values[x][i];
                   m.values[x][i] = aux;
                }
                for (x = 0; x < m.columns; x++)
                {
                   aux = m.values[j][x];
                   m.values[j][x] = m.values[i][x];
                   m.values[i][x] = aux;
                }
            }
    return m;
}

/* Exercitiul 15
   Scrieti o functie care citeste elementele unei matrici patratice de dimensiune n.
   Afisati sirul format prin parcurgerea acesteia in spirala, pornind din coltul stanga sus catre dreapta pana in centrul matricei.
*/

vector getSpiralVector(matrix m)
{
    vector v;
    v.length = 0;
    int top = 0, down = m.lines, left = 0, right = m.columns, i, j;
    bool OK = true;
    while (OK)
    {
        for (j = left; j < right; j++)
        {
            v.values[v.length] = m.values[top][j];
            v.length++;
        }
        top++;
        if (top > down || left > right) OK = false;
        for (i = top; i < down; i++)
        {
            v.values[v.length] = m.values[i][right - 1];
            v.length++;
        }
        right--;
        if (top > down || left > right)  OK = false;
        for (j = right - 1; j >= left; j--)
        {
            v.values[v.length] = m.values[down - 1][j];
            v.length++;
        }
        down--;
        if (top > down || left > right)  OK = false;
        for (i = down - 1; i >= top; i--)
        {
            v.values[v.length] = m.values[i][left];
            v.length++;
        }
        left++;
        if (top > down || left > right)  OK = false;
    }
    return v;
}

/* Exercitiul 16
   Sa se defineasca un tip pentru reprezentarea datelor calendaristice.
   Sa se scrie o functie care primeste la intrare o data calendaristica si returneaza succesorul acesteia.
   Exemplu: succesorul datei "31.10.2014" este "1.11.2014".
*/

date getNextDate(date currentDate)
{
    if (currentDate.day == 31 && currentDate.month == 12) {
        currentDate.day = 1;
        currentDate.month = 1;
        currentDate.year = currentDate.year + 1;
    }
    else if (currentDate.day < computeNumberOfDays(currentDate.year, currentDate.month))
    {
        currentDate.day = currentDate.day + 1;
    }
    else if (currentDate.day == computeNumberOfDays(currentDate.year, currentDate.month))
    {
        currentDate.day = 1;
        currentDate.month = currentDate.month + 1;
    }
    return currentDate;
}

/* Exercitiul 17
   Sa se determine ecuatia unei drepte care trece prin doua puncte in plan.
   Exemplu: pentru punctele (2, 1) si (5, 7), ecuatia dreptei este 2x â y â 3 = 0.
   Precizia pentru a, b si c va fi de 2 zecimale.
   Ecuatia va fi redusa.
*/

equation computeEquation(point point1, point point2)
{
    equation dreapta;
    dreapta.a = point2.y - point1.y;
    dreapta.b = (-1)*(point2.x - point1.x);
    dreapta.c = point1.y * point2.x - point1.x * point2.y;
    return dreapta;
}
```

this is the header file named exercises.h :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

#define MAX_ARRAY_LENGTH 100

struct vector
{
    unsigned int length;
    int values[MAX_ARRAY_LENGTH];
};

struct matrix
{
    unsigned int lines;
    unsigned int columns;
    int values[MAX_ARRAY_LENGTH][MAX_ARRAY_LENGTH];
};

struct sequence
{
    unsigned int startPosition;
    unsigned int length;
};

struct point
{
    double x;
    double y;
};

struct equation
{
    double a;
    double b;
    double c;
};

struct date
{
    unsigned int year;
    unsigned int month;
    unsigned int day;
};

/* Tema 1 */

/* Exercitiul 1
   Scrieti o functie care sa calculeze suma cifrelor unui numar natural.
*/

unsigned int computeDigitSum(unsigned int number);

/* Exercitiul 2
   Scrieti o functie care verifica daca un an este bisect.
*/

bool isLeap(unsigned int year);

/* Exercitiul 3
   Scrieti o functie care sa testeze daca un numar este palindrom.
   Un numar este palindrom daca citit de la dreapta la stanga este egal cu numarul citit de la stanga la dreapta.
   Exemple: 36463 este palindrom, dar 2646 nu este palindrom.
*/

bool isPalindrome(int number);

/* Exercitiul 4
   Scrieti un program, care, pentru o luna si un an date, calculeaza numarul de zile din luna respectiva
   (folositi o functie separata care verifica daca un an este bisect).
   Exemplu: pentru luna februarie din anul 2004, numarul de zile este 29.
*/

unsigned int computeNumberOfDays(unsigned int year, unsigned int month);

/* Exercitiul 5
   Scrieti o functie care calculeaza cifra de control a unui numar natural.
   Cifra de control se obtine calculand suma cifrelor numarului,
   apoi suma cifrelor numarului obtinut etc., pana se ajunge la o singura cifra.
   Exemplu: 4879 -> 28 -> 10 -> 1.
*/

unsigned int computeControlDigit(unsigned int number);

/* Exercitiul 6
   Spunem ca un numar natural este perfect daca este egal cu suma divizorilor sai strict mai mici decat el.
   Scrieti o functie care verifica daca un numar este perfect.
   Exemplu: 28 este un numar perfect deoarece 28 = 1 + 2 + 4 + 7 + 14. 
   Sa se determine toate numerele perfecte mai mici ca un numar natural n dat.
   Exemplu: pentru n = 1000, se vor determina numerele 6, 28, 496.
*/

bool isPerfect(unsigned int number);
vector getPerfects(unsigned int upperLimit);

/* Exercitiul 7
   Sa se testeze daca un numar este prim.
   Exemple: 1000003 este prim, dar 1000002 este compus deoarece este divizibil prin 3.
*/

bool isPrime(int number);

/* Exercitiul 8
   Doua numere naturale impare consecutive si prime se numesc numere prime gemene.
   Folosind testul de primalitate implementat anterior, determinati primele n perechi de numere prime gemene.
   Exemplu: Primele n = 3 perechi de numere prime gemene sunt (3, 5), (5, 7) si (11, 13).
*/

bool areTwinPrimes(unsigned int number1, unsigned int number2);
matrix getTwinPrimes(unsigned int count);

/* Exercitiul 9
   Se citeste un tablou de numere intregi.
   Scrieti o functie care determina diferenta maxima (in modul) dintre oricare doua elemente ale vectorului.
   Exemplu: pentru tabloul (1, 3, 2, 7, 11, 3, 2), diferenta maxima (in modul) este 12. 
*/

unsigned int getMaxDifference(vector v);

/* Exercitiul 10
   Se citeste un tablou de numere intregi.
   Sa se determine, printr-o singura parcurgere a sa, pozitia de inceput si lungimea celei mai lungi secvente de elemente egale.
   Daca exista mai multe secvente de lungimi egale, se va determina secventa cu pozitia de inceput minima.
   Exemplu: pentru tabloul (1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 5, 5, 5), se vor determina pozitia 2 si lungimea 3.
*/

sequence getMaxSequence(vector v);

/* Exercitiul 11
   Se da un vector de numere intregi.
   Sa se determine subsecventa pentru care suma elementelor componente este maxima.
   Daca exista mai multe subsecvente cu aceasta proprietate, se va determina ultima subsecventa gasita.
   Exemplu: pentru tabloul (2, 3, 4, 2, 9, 2, 1, 7, 3), subsecventa este (9, 2, 1, 7). 
*/

sequence getMaxSumSequence(vector v);

/* Exercitiul 12
   Se citeste un tablou de numere intregi.
   Sa se rearanjeze elementele astfel incat cele pare sa apara inaintea celor impare.
   In cadrul subsecventei de numere pare, respectiv impare, elementele trebuie sa apara in ordinea in care erau in tabloul initial.
   Exemplu: tabloul (2, 3, 4, 2, 9, 2, 1, 7, 3) va fi rearanjat in (2, 4, 2, 2, 3, 9, 1, 7, 3).
*/

vector orderElements(vector v);

/* Exercitiul 13
   Se considera un tablou cu n elemente.
   Sa se decida daca exista un element majoritar (cu numarul de aparitii mai mare decat n/2).
*/

bool containsMajorElement(vector v);

/* Exercitiul 14
   Se considera o matrice patratica cu n elemente.
   Sa se interschimbe liniile si coloanele acesteia astfel incat, in matricea finala, elementele de pe diagonala principala sa fie in ordine descrescatoare.
   Sa se afiseze matricea initiala si matricea dupa fiecare operatie.
*/

matrix sortDiagonalElements(matrix m);

/* Exercitiul 15
   Scrieti o functie care citeste elementele unei matrici patratice de dimensiune n.
   Afisati sirul format prin parcurgerea acesteia in spirala, pornind din coltul stanga sus catre dreapta pana in centrul matricei.
*/

vector getSpiralVector(matrix m);

/* Exercitiul 16
   Sa se defineasca un tip pentru reprezentarea datelor calendaristice.
   Sa se scrie o functie care primeste la intrare o data calendaristica si returneaza succesorul acesteia.
   Exemplu: succesorul datei "31.10.2014" este "1.11.2014".
*/

date getNextDate(date currentDate);

/* Exercitiul 17
   Sa se determine ecuatia unei drepte care trece prin doua puncte in plan.
   Exemplu: pentru punctele (2, 1) si (5, 7), ecuatia dreptei este 2x – y – 3 = 0.
   Precizia pentru a, b si c va fi de 2 zecimale.
   Ecuatia va fi redusa.
*/

equation computeEquation(point point1, point point2);
```

and i get these errors :

- 1   IntelliSense: cannot open source file "exercises.h" c:\Users\Lucian\Desktop\Facultate\IP\Teme Exercitii\B4_Cadaru.Lucian.cpp    1   1   Project2

  - 4   IntelliSense: identifier "abs" is undefined c:\Users\Lucian\Desktop\Facultate\IP\Teme Exercitii\B4_Cadaru.Lucian.cpp    131 18  Project2
  - 8   IntelliSense: identifier "abs" is undefined c:\Users\Lucian\Desktop\Facultate\IP\Teme Exercitii\B4_Cadaru.Lucian.cpp    181 22  Project2
  - 23  IntelliSense: identifier "date" is undefined    c:\Users\Lucian\Desktop\Facultate\IP\Teme Exercitii\B4_Cadaru.Lucian.cpp    381 1   Project2
  - 24  IntelliSense: identifier "date" is undefined    c:\Users\Lucian\Desktop\Facultate\IP\Teme Exercitii\B4_Cadaru.Lucian.cpp    381 18  Project2
  - 25  IntelliSense: identifier "equation" is undefined    c:\Users\Lucian\Desktop\Facultate\IP\Teme Exercitii\B4_Cadaru.Lucian.cpp    407 1   Project2
  - 28  IntelliSense: identifier "equation" is undefined    c:\Users\Lucian\Desktop\Facultate\IP\Teme Exercitii\B4_Cadaru.Lucian.cpp    409 5   Project2
  - 5   IntelliSense: identifier "matrix" is undefined  c:\Users\Lucian\Desktop\Facultate\IP\Teme Exercitii\B4_Cadaru.Lucian.cpp    152 1   Project2
  - 6   IntelliSense: identifier "matrix" is undefined  c:\Users\Lucian\Desktop\Facultate\IP\Teme Exercitii\B4_Cadaru.Lucian.cpp    154 5   Project2
  - 18  IntelliSense: identifier "matrix" is undefined  c:\Users\Lucian\Desktop\Facultate\IP\Teme Exercitii\B4_Cadaru.Lucian.cpp    307 1   Project2
  - 19  IntelliSense: identifier "matrix" is undefined  c:\Users\Lucian\Desktop\Facultate\IP\Teme Exercitii\B4_Cadaru.Lucian.cpp    307 29  Project2
  - 21  IntelliSense: identifier "matrix" is undefined  c:\Users\Lucian\Desktop\Facultate\IP\Teme Exercitii\B4_Cadaru.Lucian.cpp    335 24  Project2
  - 26  IntelliSense: identifier "point" is undefined   c:\Users\Lucian\Desktop\Facultate\IP\Teme Exercitii\B4_Cadaru.Lucian.cpp    407 26  Project2
  - 27  IntelliSense: identifier "point" is undefined   c:\Users\Lucian\Desktop\Facultate\IP\Teme Exercitii\B4_Cadaru.Lucian.cpp    407 40  Project2
  - 9   IntelliSense: identifier "sequence" is undefined    c:\Users\Lucian\Desktop\Facultate\IP\Teme Exercitii\B4_Cadaru.Lucian.cpp    195 1   Project2
  - 11  IntelliSense: identifier "sequence" is undefined    c:\Users\Lucian\Desktop\Facultate\IP\Teme Exercitii\B4_Cadaru.Lucian.cpp    197 2   Project2
  - 12  IntelliSense: identifier "sequence" is undefined    c:\Users\Lucian\Desktop\Facultate\IP\Teme Exercitii\B4_Cadaru.Lucian.cpp    228 1   Project2
  - 14  IntelliSense: identifier "sequence" is undefined    c:\Users\Lucian\Desktop\Facultate\IP\Teme Exercitii\B4_Cadaru.Lucian.cpp    230 5   Project2
  - 2   IntelliSense: identifier "vector" is undefined  c:\Users\Lucian\Desktop\Facultate\IP\Teme Exercitii\B4_Cadaru.Lucian.cpp    106 1   Project2
  - 3   IntelliSense: identifier "vector" is undefined  c:\Users\Lucian\Desktop\Facultate\IP\Teme Exercitii\B4_Cadaru.Lucian.cpp    108 5   Project2
  - 7   IntelliSense: identifier "vector" is undefined  c:\Users\Lucian\Desktop\Facultate\IP\Teme Exercitii\B4_Cadaru.Lucian.cpp    174 31  Project2
  - 10  IntelliSense: identifier "vector" is undefined  c:\Users\Lucian\Desktop\Facultate\IP\Teme Exercitii\B4_Cadaru.Lucian.cpp    195 25  Project2
  - 13  IntelliSense: identifier "vector" is undefined  c:\Users\Lucian\Desktop\Facultate\IP\Teme Exercitii\B4_Cadaru.Lucian.cpp    228 28  Project2
  - 15  IntelliSense: identifier "vector" is undefined  c:\Users\Lucian\Desktop\Facultate\IP\Teme Exercitii\B4_Cadaru.Lucian.cpp    261 1   Project2
  - 16  IntelliSense: identifier "vector" is undefined  c:\Users\Lucian\Desktop\Facultate\IP\Teme Exercitii\B4_Cadaru.Lucian.cpp    261 22  Project2
  - 17  IntelliSense: identifier "vector" is undefined  c:\Users\Lucian\Desktop\Facultate\IP\Teme Exercitii\B4_Cadaru.Lucian.cpp    287 27  Project2
  - 20  IntelliSense: identifier "vector" is undefined  c:\Users\Lucian\Desktop\Facultate\IP\Teme Exercitii\B4_Cadaru.Lucian.cpp    335 1   Project2
  - 22  IntelliSense: identifier "vector" is undefined  c:\Users\Lucian\Desktop\Facultate\IP\Teme Exercitii\B4_Cadaru.Lucian.cpp    337 5   Project2

I used Visual Studio . How can i get this solved ?

Comment: Did you add exercises.h to the project ?

Comment: yes i put it in header files

Comment: Is your exercice.h file linked to the project or is it in the following directory: c:\Users\Lucian\Desktop\Facultate\IP\Teme Exercitii\?

Comment: it`s neither of them i don`t know how to link it

Answer (score 1):

Check the header file is in the project, as Paul R said.

On another note, it's probably not a great idea to use 'vector' as a name for your struct, and I generally don't add 'using namespace std;' in a header file, as anyone who includes the header gets the std namespace visible, whether they need it or not. In your case it also makes the using namespace line in the CPP file redundant.

Answer (score 1):

You have to ensure that you're giving the compiler the correct path of the `exercises.h` file. In case you forgot to add it to your project, open `Project settings > C++ > Include directories` and select the folder where `exercises.h` is present.

Comment: this worked all the errors are gone but new ones came :

Comment: Error 7 error C2088: '[' : illegal for struct c:\users\lucian\desktop\facultate\ip\teme exercitii\b4_cadaru.lucian.cpp 199 1 Project2

Comment: Error 6 error C2676: binary '[' : 'vector' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator c:\users\lucian\desktop\facultate\ip\teme exercitii\b4_cadaru.lucian.cpp 199 1 Project2

Comment: forget these one i managed to fix them but this one is hard Error 21 error LNK1561: entry point must be defined C:\Users\Lucian\Desktop\Facultate\IP\Teme Exercitii\Project2\Project2\LINK Project2

Comment: Are you missing `int main()` by any chance?

Comment: of course . now everything works fine . thank you all

Comment: @user2907139, it's advisable to accept an answer once the problem has been solved. Read about it [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).